# Read Lines, Process to List, and Write to File in PYTHON

Tags: python, twitter

I am very new in Python and I am processing the tweets below:

```
@PrincessSuperC Hey Cici sweetheart! Just wanted to let u know I luv u! OH! and will the mixtape drop soon? FANTASY RIDE MAY 5TH!!!!  
@Msdebramaye I heard about that contest! Congrats girl!! 
UNC!!! NCAA Champs!! Franklin St.: I WAS THERE!! WILD AND CRAZY!!!!!! Nothing like it...EVER http://tinyurl.com/49955t3
Do you Share More #jokes #quotes #music #photos or #news #articles on #Facebook or #Twitter?
Good night #Twitter and #TheLegionoftheFallen.  5:45am cimes awfully early!
I just finished a 2.66 mi run with a pace of 11'14"/mi with Nike+ GPS. #nikeplus #makeitcount
Disappointing day. Attended a car boot sale to raise some funds for the sanctuary, made a total of 88p after the entry fee - sigh
no more taking Irish car bombs with strange Australian women who can drink like rockstars...my head hurts.
Just had some bloodwork done. My arm hurts
```

And it supposed to have an output of a feature vectors as follows:

```
featureList = ['hey', 'cici', 'luv', 'mixtape', 'drop', 'soon', 'fantasy', 'ride', 'heard', 
'congrats', 'ncaa', 'franklin', 'wild', 'share', 'jokes', 'quotes', 'music', 'photos', 'news',
'articles', 'facebook', 'twitter', 'night', 'twitter', 'thelegionofthefallen', 'cimes', 'awfully',
'finished', 'mi', 'run', 'pace', 'gps', 'nikeplus', 'makeitcount', 'disappointing', 'day', 'attended',
'car', 'boot', 'sale', 'raise', 'funds', 'sanctuary', 'total', 'entry', 'fee', 'sigh', 'taking',
'irish', 'car', 'bombs', 'strange', 'australian', 'women', 'drink', 'head', 'hurts', 'bloodwork', 
'arm', 'hurts']
```

However, the current output that i got is only

```
hey, cici, luv, mixtape, drop, soon, fantasy, ride
```

which comes from the first tweet only. And it keeps loopping in that one tweet only without going to the next line.. I tried to use nextLine but apparently it does not work on Python. My code is as follows:

```
#import regex
import re
import csv
import pprint
import nltk.classify

#start replaceTwoOrMore
def replaceTwoOrMore(s):
    #look for 2 or more repetitions of character
    pattern = re.compile(r"(.)\1{1,}", re.DOTALL) 
    return pattern.sub(r"\1\1", s)
#end

#start process_tweet
def processTweet(tweet):
    # process the tweets

    #Convert to lower case
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    #Convert www.* or https?://* to URL
    tweet = re.sub('((www\.[\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',tweet)
    #Convert @username to AT_USER
    tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+','AT_USER',tweet)    
    #Remove additional white spaces
    tweet = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', tweet)
    #Replace #word with word
    tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', tweet)
    #trim
    tweet = tweet.strip('\'"')
    return tweet
#end 

#start getStopWordList
def getStopWordList(stopWordListFileName):
    #read the stopwords
    stopWords = []
    stopWords.append('AT_USER')
    stopWords.append('URL')

    fp = open(stopWordListFileName, 'r')
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        word = line.strip()
        stopWords.append(word)
        line = fp.readline()
    fp.close()
    return stopWords
#end

#start getfeatureVector
#start getfeatureVector
def getFeatureVector(tweet):
    featureVector = []
    #split tweet into words
    words = tweet.split()
    for w in words:
        #replace two or more with two occurrences
        w = replaceTwoOrMore(w)
        #strip punctuation
        w = w.strip('\'"?,.')
        #check if the word stats with an alphabet
        val = re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$", w)
        #ignore if it is a stop word
        if(w in stopWords or val is None):
            continue
        else:
            featureVector.append(w.lower())
    return featureVector
#end

#Read the tweets one by one and process it
fp = open('data/sampleTweets.txt', 'r')
line = fp.readline()

st = open('data/feature_list/stopwords.txt', 'r')
stopWords = getStopWordList('data/feature_list/stopwords.txt')

while line:
    processedTweet = processTweet(line)
    featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet)
    with open('data/niek_corpus_feature_vector.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(', '.join(featureVector))
#end loop
fp.close()
```

UPDATE:
After trying to change the loop as suggested below:

```
st = open('data/feature_list/stopwords.txt', 'r')
stopWords = getStopWordList('data/feature_list/stopwords.txt')

with open('data/sampleTweets.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        processedTweet = processTweet(line)
        featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet)
        with open('data/niek_corpus_feature_vector.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(', '.join(featureVector))
fp.close()
```

I got the following output, which is only the the words from the last line of the tweets.

```
bloodwork, arm, hurts
```

I am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: What's the relation betweent the expected output and the input? It seems like you're just picking words randomly.

Comment: The output is the important keyword (feature vector) as processed by getFeatureVector method. The problem here is that I can't seem to go to the next line. Not about how to select the words.

Comment: .readline() reads only single line .You will have to put the whole stuff in a loop if you wan to read one process that and read again and process that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want use readline() and not readlines use a loop as follows.

```
st = open('data/feature_list/stopwords.txt', 'r')
stopWords = getStopWordList('data/feature_list/stopwords.txt')
with open('data/sampleTweets.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        processedTweet = processTweet(line)
        featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet)
        with open('data/niek_corpus_feature_vector.txt', 'ab') as f:
            f.write(', '.join(featureVector))
```

Comment: When I tried this, the output only contains the words from the last line of the tweet, which are: **bloodwork, arm, hurts**. I am still trying to figure out why..

Comment: ohh when opening the file  with `open('data/niek_corpus_feature_vector.txt', 'w') as f:` use `a` for append instead of `w` for writing.w destroys previous file contents `open('data/niek_corpus_feature_vector.txt', 'a') as f:` .I will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
line = fp.readline()
```

only reads a single line in the file. You then process that line in the while and exit immediately thereafter. You need to read every line in the file. Once you have read the entire file, you should then process each line as you have already done.

```
lines = fp.readlines()

# Now process each line

for line in lines:
  # Now process the line as you do in your original code
  while line:
    processedTweet = processTweet(line)
```

[Python File readlines() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm)

The method `readlines()` reads until EOF using `readline()`
and returns a list containing the lines. If the optional sizehint
argument is present, instead of reading up to EOF, whole lines
totalling approximately sizehint bytes (possibly after rounding up to
an internal buffer size) are read.

Following is the syntax for readlines() method:

```
fileObject.readlines( sizehint ); Parameters sizehint -- This is the number of bytes to be read from the file.

Return Value: This method returns a list containing the lines.
```

Example The following example shows the usage of `readlines()` method.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 # Open a file 
fo = open("foo.txt", "rw+") print "Name of the file: ", fo.name

 # Assuming file has following 5 lines
 # This is 1st line
 # This is 2nd line
 # This is 3rd line
 # This is 4th line
 # This is 5th line

line = fo.readlines() print "Read Line: %s" % (line)

line = fo.readlines(2) print "Read Line: %s" % (line)

# Close opend file 

fo.close()
```

Let us compile and run the above program, this will produce the following result:

```
 Name of the file:  foo.txt Read Line: ['This is 1st line\n', 'This is
 2nd line\n', 
             'This is 3rd line\n', 'This is 4th line\n', 
             'This is 5th line\n'] 
Read Line: []
```

Comment: @Stormvirux I had copied the original site to show it exactly. I tend to think that when quoting a site, one she show it exactly and not change the wording.